# Matches showing in words as oppose to number in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a select statement that is trying to select matches from the database, but after I get the results, the matches are in words, instead of being in numbers.

```
SELECT DATA ,  
"CASE WHEN data LIKE  '%one two%' THEN 2 
ELSE CASE WHEN data LIKE '%one%' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
END
END" AS  'matches'
FROM remember
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Result:**

column matches:

```
"CASE WHEN data LIKE  '%love%' THEN 2" ELSE CASE W...
"CASE WHEN data LIKE  '%love%' THEN 2" ELSE CASE W...
"CASE WHEN data LIKE  '%love%' THEN 2" ELSE CASE W...
```

**Expected Result:**

column matches:

```
2
1
0
```

Comment: What's that double-quote before `CASE`? Is this really the real, untampered query?

Comment: @VolkerK Huh? Without the double quote before and after the string, the database will just throw an error.

Comment: And with those quotes you get the string literal back as the result.

Comment: @VolkerK So, your suggestion?

Comment: @VolkerK What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need CASE multiple times:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN data LIKE  '%one two%' THEN 2 
            WHEN data LIKE '%one%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END AS  'matches'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Gotta start somewhere, glad I could help. :D